How to adjust the layout of the Screen in React Native
I am designing a screen "Change Password". There are three Textinput fields out of them one is designed and adjusted correctly, but the other are not adjusting properly. They are not getting the full screen width. The code is attached for your reference.
return (
    <View className='h-full w-full bg-white'>
      <Image className='h-full w-full absolute' source={require('../src/images/background.png')}/>
      
      {/* Lights */}
      <View className='flex-row justify-around w-full absolute'>
        <Animated.Image entering={FadeInUp.delay(200).duration(1000).springify().damping(2)} className='h-[225] w-[90]' source={require("../src/images/light.png")}/>
        <Animated.Image entering={FadeInUp.delay(400).duration(1000).springify().damping(2)} className='h-[160] w-[65]' source={require("../src/images/light.png")}/>
      </View>

      {/* Ttitle And Forms */}
      <View className='h-full w-full flex justify-around pt-40 pb-10'>
        {/* Ttitle */}
        <View className='flex items-center'>
            <Animated.Text entering={FadeInUp.duration(1500).springify()} className='text-white font-bold tracking-wider text-5xl'>Change Password</Animated.Text>
          </View>

          {/* first Input */}
          <View className='flex items-center mx-4 space-y-4'>
          <View className='bg-black/5 p-1 rounded-2xl w-full'>
          <TextInput
              placeholder="Email"
              value={email}
                onChangeText={(text) => setEmail(text)}
                />
                </View>
                {error ? (
        <Text style={{ color: 'red' }}>{error}</Text>
      ) : null}
      {!showPasswordInput ? (
        <TouchableOpacity className='bg-sky-300 w-full p-2 rounded-2xl' onPress={handleForgotPassword}>
          <Text className='text-white text-center'>Submit</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ) : (
        <View>
          <TextInput
            placeholder="New Password"
            value={password}
            onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)}
            secureTextEntry
          />
          <TextInput
            placeholder="Confirm New Password"
            value={confirmPassword}
            onChangeText={(text) => setConfirmPassword(text)}
            secureTextEntry
          />
          <Button title="Reset Password" onPress={handleResetPassword} />
        </View>
      )}
    </View>

          </View>
          </View>

      
      
      
  )  
};



Did you try assigning the className w-full to the wrapper View of password fields container? e.g.


<View className='w-full'>
      <TextInput
        placeholder="New Password"
        value={password}
        onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)}
        secureTextEntry
      />
      <TextInput
        placeholder="Confirm New Password"
        value={confirmPassword}
        onChangeText={(text) => setConfirmPassword(text)}
        secureTextEntry
      />
      <Button title="Reset Password" onPress={handleResetPassword} />
 </View>



